# Jenkins build for the branch on the triggered branch?

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job that triggers when a branch is updated.

The branch specifier is set to Any:
`Branch Specifier (blank for 'any')`

However, I find that the Build Steps are executed on the Latest branch, rather than on the branch which pushes to it triggered the Jenkins job.

The build output shows:

```
+refs/pull/${ghprbPullId}/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/${ghprbPullId}/* 
Seen branch in repository origin/1 
Seen branch in repository origin/2 
Seen branch in repository origin/3 
Seen branch in repository origin/4 
Seen branch in repository origin/5
Seen branch in repository origin/master 
Seen branch in repository origin/6 
Seen branch in repository origin/7
Seen branch in repository origin/8 
Seen branch in repository origin/9
Seen 10 remote branches
```

A push to branch `origin/7` triggered the Jenkins job, however the Build steps are executed on branch `origin/1`.

How do I ensure that the Build steps execute on the same branch that triggers the job? (In my case, `origin/7`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more than one solution. It is depends from where you trigger the job and how job is configured.

As examples:

**If it is simple job**, you can set parameter to it configuration and pass it through your hooks (you probably need [parameterized builds for Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build)):

Add parameter to your Job:

[image]

And then set parameter's value to the branch to build (via `$ParameterName`):

[image]

**If trigger is custom**, from your application for example - you should pass value via calling `http://yourJenkinsServer/job/myJobName/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN&PARAMETER=Value`

More details you can find in documentation of plugin. `Token` here is Jenkins security token for your account.

**If you trigger job via VCS**: you also can pass this parameter, it depends on what VCS Server you use and which abilities it has to do it. As example, for Bitbucket Server it can be:

- [Trigger parameterized builds in Jenkins from Bitbucket Server](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1213179/parameterized-builds-for-jenkins?hosting=server&tab=overview)
- [Pull Request Notifier for Bitbucket Server](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/pull-request-notifier-for-bitbucket)

So you need to find what fit to your VCS server.

As additional example: **for multibranch pipeline projects** you can simply use environment variable `BRANCH_NAME` and use `git branch: "${BRANCH_NAME}"` inside your pipeline code. And it is more easy setup and to use.